# Will Game Data be Erased from iOS Restore if Connected to Game Center?

Tags: ios, ipad, restore

After forgetting my passcode for my iPad, I have decided that I need to restore my iPad through recovery mode (which I am aware that it will completely erase everything else). However, will that erase my Apple ID and Game Center data? In other words, if I restore and wipe my iPad clean, then enter again and download my game and sign in to Game Center, will all that game progress still be saved somewhere online or something via Game Center or Apple ID, or is all that information only stored in the iPad itself and not online/in a cloud/etc and will be lost?

Answer (score 1):

I have done this before and no, it does not erase your Apple ID or Game Center data. However, not all applications and games use Game Center or iCloud to store data so keep that in mind.